# making selenium click on specfic element

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I want to open this page https://www.tesla.com/en_gb/models/design#battery and click the performance button programmatically with python.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser = webdriver.Chrome('../Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://www.tesla.com/en_gb/models/design#battery')
A = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='group--options_block_title']/span/p")
time.sleep(30)
A.click();
```

i thought the problem might be that the page didnt have time to load but giving it 30 seconds didnt help.

if it works the range should be 367 not 379

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code sometime sites are taking too long while loading so would be great if you use WebDriverWait in your solution. Also its not good practice to use Abs XPath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://www.tesla.com/en_gb/models/design#battery')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(text(),'Performance')]")))
print element.text
element.click()
element1 = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'367')]")))
print element1.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector finds 2 elements, and first of them isn't performance.
Try this one:

```
//div[@role='button' and @aria-label='Performance']
```

So it seems like you were actually clicking, but one element that was already active.